# Gradle download full dependency-of-dependency chain?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

We are currently utilizing Artifactory in our organization and I'm having a bit of trouble getting an entire dependency chain downloaded.  For instance, we have the following dependency listed in our project:

```
compile group: 'org.jbpm', name: 'jbpm-flow-builder', version: droolsVersion
```

This package relies on a chain of dependencies like so:

```
jbpm-flow-builder
└───jbpm
    └───kie-parent-with-dependencies
        └───kie-platform-bom
            └───jboss-integration-platform-bom
```

Unfortunately the `jboss-integration-platform-bom` has hundreds of other sub-dependencies in the chain.

I've attempted several ways at downloading all of the required transitive dependencies to no avail as it seems nothing I do fully traverses the chain and I have to build, manually download, upload into Artifactory, rinse and repeat.  For instance, this did not work:

```
configurations {
    compile {
        transitive = true
    }
}

...

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'dependencies'
}
```

I do not have direct access to Artifactory to perform uploads so I need an efficient way to download the entire dependency chain and associated POMs into a single folder.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I asked in my initial question but in a very hacky way.  First of all, I cleared out my `%userprofile%\.gradle\caches` folder to ensure that it was completely clean.

Next, I commented out any internal-specific dependencies in my `build.gradle` and ensured that my buildscript repositories and main repositories were pointed at `mavenLocal` and `mavenCentral` as shown below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

From here, I went ahead and build the application and let all the dependencies download.  I was then able to write a quick and simple PowerShell script to pull all of the cached POM and JAR files into a temporary directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\ -Filter *.pom | %{  Copy-Item $_.FullName C:\temp\jar\ }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\ -Filter *.jar | %{  Copy-Item $_.FullName C:\temp\jar\ }
```

From here, I do not have access to the Artifactory API endpoint, so I proceeded to write another quick script which checked for the existence of the artifacts in Artifactory and if they already exist, then script will remove them from the folder to provide only the necessary artifacts to upload in:

```
function Get-Artifact($JsessionId, $SearchString) {
 $session = New-Object Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.WebRequestSession
 $cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie
 $cookie.name = "JSESSIONID"
 $cookie.Value = $jsessionId
 $cookie.Domain = "artifactory.domain.com" 
 $session.Cookies.Add($cookie)
 $body = @{"query" = $searchString; "search" = "quick"; "selectedRepositories" = @()} | ConvertTo-JSON   
 $headers = @{"Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
 return ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://artifactory.domain.com:8081/artifactory/ui/artifactsearch/quick -Method POST -WebSession $session -Headers $headers -Body $body).Content | ConvertFrom-Json).results.length
}

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\jar | % { If((Get-Artifact -jsessionId "<session ID here>" -searchString $_.Name) -eq 0) { $_.Name } Else { Remove-Item $_.FullName } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you'd like to download the whole dependency tree in order to build your project. I recommend using the greater artifactory plugin to build your gradle project. It will download all your project dependencies, including transitive dependencies, build your project, publish your build artifacts to artifactory and also collect and publish build info to artifactory.

See the plugin communication [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin). See also a few project examples [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot utilize this route as I do not have upload permission for Artifactory.  I need a way to pull all JAR and POM files directly into a folder to provide to an engineer with access to upload.

Comment: With the Grade Artifactory Plugin you don't have to upload the artifacts to Artifactory at the end of the build. You can use the plugin for dependencies resolution only.

Comment: How does this differentiate from utilizing the the standard "repositories" section in the DSL and simply adding the public repositories?  I don't have any issue pulling from public and building the project, but I am trying to get the entire dependency chain (everything pulled down from public) into Artifactory.